# Dynamic checkbox onclick is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating dynamic checkboxes and want a function to be called every time I check any checkbox. The checkbox looks good but my onclick event does not work. Also if I do not pass 'this' to my function, my function gets called on load as well.
Below is my code:

```
for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
  var op = options[i].new_name;     
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var description = document.createTextNode(op);

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";    
  checkbox.name = "multiselectCheckbox";
  checkbox.value = op;
  checkbox.onclick= "getCheckedValues(this)";

  label.appendChild(checkbox);   
  label.appendChild(description);

  document.getElementById("multiselect").appendChild(label);    
  document.getElementById("multiselect").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: I have posted my code snippet above. This is all I have to share :(

Comment: -Priyanka, `options` is undefined..Use `checkbox.setAttribute('click',"getCheckedValues(this)");`

Comment: Sorry Rayon.. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snippet works. I suppose this is what you want to do. You need not pass `this` in the function and also call the function without `""`

```js
var options = [{new_name: "1"}, {new_name: "2"}]
for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
  var op = options[i].new_name;  
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var description = document.createTextNode(op);

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";    
  checkbox.name = "multiselectCheckbox";
  checkbox.value = op;
  checkbox.onclick = getCheckedValues;

  label.appendChild(checkbox);   
  label.appendChild(description);

  document.getElementById("multiselect").appendChild(label);    
  document.getElementById("multiselect").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}

function getCheckedValues() {
  alert(this.value);  
}
```

```html
<div id="multiselect"></div>
```